# Adding text in tinyxml2

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml2

I am trying to create an XML file using TinyXML2. While there are many examples and tutorials on loading, there seems to be very little on saving.

I basically want to end up with:

```xml
<node>text</node>
```

I know I can get the "node" parts by adding an element, but how do I set the text part? Element has a `GetText` but I can find no `SetText`. There is also an `XMLText` class, but that has no methods for setting the text!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I built with G++ 4.2.1 on OS X 10.6, and it runs fine. Output is `<Version>1.0.0</Version>`.

```
#include "tinyxml2.h"

using namespace tinyxml2;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   tinyxml2::XMLDocument doc;
   tinyxml2::XMLElement* versionNode = doc.NewElement("Version");
   tinyxml2::XMLText* versionText = doc.NewText("1.0.0");

   versionNode->InsertEndChild(versionText);
   doc.InsertEndChild(versionNode);

   XMLPrinter printer;
   doc.Print();

   return 0;
}
```